# Download manager does not exist

Tags: google-play-store, 5.1-lollipop, download-manager

I've bought Chinese Meizu m2 mini and there is no Download Manager app at all. I can download from Web by ES explorer's downloader facility, but I can't do anything with Google Play. My firmware is 4.5.3.2A, so if someone can help me - I'll be really appreciate.

Comment: Are you certain that you haven't mistakenly disabled it sometime ago? Confirm us whether it is present in Settings -> All apps or under Disabled apps.

Comment: There are no presented "Download Manager" in all apps. There is a question - I don't even have one on my phone.

Comment: Google Play (app) doesn't use arbitrary download manager, unless you're talking about Google Play web. Also, in most phones (at least on Nexus with stock Android), "download manager" is not displayed on home screen. Anyway, I think the problem is something related to Google Play connection, not particularly about download manager.